# Changing the file name before uploading to file path with move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, html

```html
$date = date('m-d-Y_H:i:s');
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    // Allow certain file formats
    //$newfilestring = $date.$lastname.$firstname;
    $targetDir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/uploaded-file/";
    $fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir.$fileName;
    $extension = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf','xlsx');
    $empid = $_SESSION['id'];

    if(in_array($extension, $allowTypes)){
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $con->query("INSERT into fileupload (filename, dateuploaded,empid) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW(), '".$empid."')");
            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = "Your timesheet: ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
            }
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, xlsx & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}
```

```html
  <form class="formSub-Form" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <h3>EX Sheets</h3>

                    <p>*Please only submit files in a .pdf format.</p>

                    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="file">


                    <div id="lower">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

This is the php & html file. As of right now I am able to upload the file with the name it was uploaded with. My goal is to change the file name to the format of the 'newfilestring'(that is commented out) and then add the extension of the file that was uploaded. I have tested multiple methods and tutorials and none of them work. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Current format -> example.pdf

Desired format -> date-firstname-lastname-extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like this:

`$newFileName = $date.$lastname.$firstname.'.'.$extension;` // Provided these variables have been supplied elsewhere

And then use it when moving the file:

`if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetDir.$newFileName )){` // etc.

Have not tested this, but will hopefully put you on the right track...

UPDATED: Try this:

```
$date = date('m-d-Y');
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    // Allow certain file formats
    $targetDir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/uploaded-file/";
    $fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $filename_array = explode(".",$fileName ); // get file name
    $extension = $filename_array[1]; // second portion of file name - extension
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir.$fileName;
    $newFileName = $date.$lastname.$firstname.'.'.$extension;

    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf','xlsx');
    $empid = $_SESSION['id'];

    if(in_array($extension, $allowTypes)){
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetDir.$newFileName )){
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $con->query("INSERT into fileupload (filename, dateuploaded,empid) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW(), '".$empid."')");
            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = "Your timesheet: ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
            }
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, xlsx & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}
```

Comment: If I change the $fileName variable then the $targetPath variable changes, which in turn does not return me an extension because I am not looking at the original file.

Comment: So, now the if(move_uploaded_file) returns false and sends me to my else statement.

Comment: Try $newFileName = "test_filename";

Comment: Are you defining first and last name? Also, I noticed your $date includes the time with colons. You can't use colons in file names on many systems. Remove those.

Comment: The first and last name variables are defined. I removed the time from the date object. I assigned the $newFileName ="test_filename" and got the same result(moved_uploaded_file returns false and sends me to else statement).

Comment: I've updated the full code to a revised suggestion. (needed to update the filename with the path on the move)

Comment: Noticed that the logic for the file extension wouldn't work because it was trying to find the path of the file and it's extension before the file was located there. Changed the method in my revised code.

Comment: Added the extension to the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$extension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir.$date.'-'.$firstName.'-'.$lastname.'.'.$extension;
```

to rename the file.

Comment: If I change the $targetPath variable, then I will not have an extension to concatenate.

Comment: I tried this method of doing it and I receive a 'WARNING: move_uploaded_file(directory): failed to open stream: No such file or directory found in 'file path to php'

Comment: Yes, there might be some slashes or directory separators missing.